# How to avoid eclipse to create 2 lines when autoindent is ON?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse code-formatting options are vast (see Java -> CodeStyle -> code formatting)

What I want  is to avoid that the autoindent  split my lines of code in  2 (or more) lines (see below). When reading-debugging code, is far more clear to read complete lines (IMHO)

Ex

```
float vsleep = (float) (((nodelenght) * obj
.getFactorperchar()) * 1000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to stop eclipse from wrapping text over one or more lines.

If you navigate to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Code Style -> Formatter and then click "Edit" next to the active profile, you can edit all of the auto formatting options. Choose the Line Wrapping tab, and then select all of the options in the list that contains "Class Declarations", "Constructor Declarations" and so on. Underneath the list, set the Line wrapping policy to "Do not wrap".

I tested this in my version and it seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `Line Wrapping -> Maximum line width` to something larger.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @Massimiliano Of course it's an answer. It might not be what the OP needs to do but it is an answer and it does address the issue of line wrapping.